# Sort MySQL results alphabetically, but with numbers last

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, alphabetical-sort

Often, sorting is done with symbols sorted to the top, like `0` or `*` or `&`.  This is the default way that mysql sorts; numbers and symbols and then A-Z.  However, that makes the often ugliest or most badly formatted results float to the top (e.g. a result of `@#$@3423` or `8 inch` or `&amp`).

So I'd like to do a modified form of that, letters first A-Z, and then special characters last.

How would I go about creating that type of sort? Something in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>Based on a google-cached link to this page:
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.feedmarker.com%2F2006%2F02%2F01%2Fhow-to-do-natural-alpha-numeric-sort-in-mysql%2F&ei=Zg2_TZyKDaffiALjjqwo&usg=AFQjCNGS-rX7AmfrumXK8J7bVSj96bSSmQ</s>

EDIT: Original link is dead.
Here is another link which actually explains what is happening better than the first link did:

http://matthewturland.com/2008/11/05/natural-ordering-in-mysql/

You might try this

```
SELECT names FROM your_table ORDER BY names + 0 ASC
```

Comment: Hmmm, can't get directly to the cached link for it.

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fX1EQOT_ASMJ:blog.feedmarker.com/2006/02/01/how-to-do-natural-alpha-numeric-sort-in-mysql/+blog.feedmarker.com/2006/02/01/how-to-do-natural-alpha-numeric-sort-in-&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com That cached link should work.  Not sure -why- the added 0 works, but it does!

Comment: How could that possibly work with something like `ABC0123DEF` vs `ABCDEFGHIJKL`?

Comment: @Thomas I have to be honest, I'm not sure why it works either.

Comment: From what I've read, I think this may only when the first character is numeric. I'm not at a spot where I can run a test, but I'd be interested to know if this works against variants such as `ABC0123456`, `ABC0123DEF`, `0123456ABC`, `ABCDEFGHI`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen ... thanks for the heads-up, I changed to a new and better link!

Answer (score 6):

```
Select ...
From ...
Order By Case When Col Like '[0-9]%' Then 1 Else 0 End Asc
    , Col
```

Another solution that would account for special characters:

```
Select ...
From ...
Order By Case When Col Like '[A-Z]%' Then 0 Else 1 End Asc
    , Col
```

Comment: This only addresses the first character of the string. I assume the OP wants the sort logic to apply to the entire string. For example,  `aa` should sort above `a1` and `a!`.

Comment: Yeah a consistent sort alteration would be nice.

Comment: @Tchalvak - Do you mean you want `ABC123` to sort after `ABDEFG`? If so, there is no simple means to do that. Your best bet might be to use a regex replace to replace digits with something that sorts near the bottom like a "Z" and sort on that.

Comment: @Tchalvak - Btw, is it that the special characters or digits are always at the end instead of the beginning or is it that they are in the middle of the text?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM `yourTable` ORDER BY `yourDatabase`.`yourColumn`  ASC
```

Comment: Nope, that'll show the numbers first, then the letters, whereas DESC will go z to a then 9 to 0, neither of which are ideal.   The accepted answer works just fine, though.