# Mysql sorting using numbers and characters

Tags: mysql, sorting

I am having a mysql table field with mixed values.Say,

```
1
2
Priya
Radha
```

If I sorts this in ascending order, the result will be displayed as shown above and if I sorts in descending order, the result will be

```
Radha
Priya
2
1
```

Here Mysql will give priority to numbers and then characters.

What to do, if I want Mysql to give priority  to characters?
ie, Sorting in ascending order should give a result like the one below:

```
Priya
Radha
1
2
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort mysql results alphabetically, but with numbers last.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861852/sort-mysql-results-alphabetically-but-with-numbers-last)

Answer (score 1):

I found this, maybe you can try it.

[Sorting characters and numbers in mysql](http://www.carlos-roque.com/2011/04/19/sorting-characters-and-numbers-in-mysql/)