# ORDER BY varchar with [a-9] instead of [0-Z] in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

By default, SQL orders numbers before characters.

So if I have the column "name":

```
abc
ab1
a1b
1ba
1bac
b21
```

Since SQL sorts by 0-Z (first 0 to 9, then a-Z), the query

```
SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY name
```

will result in:

```
1ba
1bac
a1b
ab1
abc
abc1
b21
```

But I want it to sort by a-0 (first a-Z, then 0-9).

```
abc
abc1
ab1
a1b
b21
1ba
1bac
```

How do I do this in a query? More specifically, how do I do this in SQLite?

I found one solution in *[Sort MySQL results alphabetically, but with numbers last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861852/sort-mysql-results-alphabetically-but-with-numbers-last)*, but only for first char.

Comment: Are your values always 3 characters long?

Comment: You could [use the C interface to create a function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that uses the [`regexp`](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) operator to yank out the letters and numbers into separate columns.

Comment: @gbn No, they can very in length.. Should probably have shown that :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest `SELECT`ing another column, say `name_replace`, with the digits replaced by a high-ASCII character (such as `~`), then sorting on that column then on name. Unfortunately SQLite doesn't have support for [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) replace:

```
SELECT name, replace( ... replace(replace(name, '0', '~'), '1', '~') ... '9', '~') AS name_replace
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY name_replace, name
```

The digits will come last when sorting on `name_replace`. Sorting on `name` will then order by the digits.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick with the data provided.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
ORDER BY Name COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC037_CP1_CS_AS
```

However you may want to look into the various collation types to ensure it does what you want across the board.

UPDATE: You mentioned SQLite however I tested this on MSSQL. Not sure if this collation is available in SQLite but comments below may have useful info.

Comment: OP actually mentioned SQLite, but this could work - I don't know if there is an existing collation sequence in SQLite that would do the trick, however - might have to create one.

Comment: as @DavidFaber pointed out, the actual target platform is SQLite.
I found http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html 
But I can't really understand if this solution is doable in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Test with these data please

```
declare @t table(a char(3))
insert @t values('ab1')
insert @t values('a1b')
insert @t values('1ba')
insert @t values('b21')
insert @t values('12a')
insert @t values('13b')


select a,
patindex('[0-9]%', a + 'a'), 
patindex('_[0-9]%', a + 'a'), 
patindex('__[0-9]%', a + 'a')
from @t order by 2, 3, 4, 1
```

or

```
select a
from 
(select a,
patindex('[0-9]%', a + 'a') b, 
patindex('_[0-9]%', a + 'a') c, 
patindex('__[0-9]%', a + 'a') d
from @t) e
order by b, c, d, a
```

Comment: I don't believe that this is valid SQLite syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea: you add another "help_column" that checks if the first char is a number and assign 1 to it, otherwise assign 0 and then order by this column and then by name:

```
select *, case
             when substring(name,1,1) like '[0-9]' then 1 
             else 0 
          end as help_order
from (
select 'ab1' as name union select 'a1b' as name union select '1ba' as name union select 'b21' as name
) a
order by help_order, name
```

Of course, you may have to improve the regular expression [0-9] to treat more than one number if necessary.

And, of course, you should replace the inner query (the one with several unions with your table).

Comment: This will only work for the first character (I made the same mistake in my first try)

Answer (score 0):

Thsi substitutes 0-9 to above ASCII 122 (which is lower case z).

SQLLite doesn't have a CHAR function to do the substitution by character code (eg `CHAR(123)` to `CHAR(132)`) which may be needed instead of my CHAR(123) attempt

Untested of course :-)

```
ORDER BY
   REPLACE
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
   REPLACE(name, '0', '{0')
    , '1', '{2')
    , '2', '{2')
    , '3', '{3')
    , '4', '{4')
    , '5', '{5')
    , '6', '{6')
    , '7', '{7')
    , '8', '{8')
    , '9', '{9')
```

Edit: although, @David Faber's solution does the same but somewhat simpler...