# Symfony doctrine Alphanumerical order

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I need to sort data from database in alphanumerical order. For example, we have that data: 1,A,B,C,2,3,10. After sorting must be: 1,2,3,10,A,B,C.
That how it will work in MySQL:

```
SELECT Name FROM garden ORDER BY Name=0,-Name DESC, Name
```

How to do something like that in symfony doctrine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort MySQL results alphabetically, but with numbers last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861852/sort-mysql-results-alphabetically-but-with-numbers-last) (while the other question asks numbers to be sorted last and you them to be sorted first, the [link provided in the answer](http://matthewturland.com/2008/11/05/natural-ordering-in-mysql/) should solve your question)